# Where is the ~/.eclipse folder in Mac OS X?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, eclipse

I want to copy the `~/.eclipse` folder from Linux to OS X so that I don't have to reconfigure it again. Please help me find this folder.

Comment: Not really a mac person, but have you tried looking in ~/Library or something similar? I think that's where most of these things go in OS X.

Comment: i have searched for eclipse in the finder, but none of the results were in the /Library folder.

Answer (score 2):

OS X is based on Unix and Eclipse has not changed anything – in OS X there is a `~/.eclipse` directory.

Comment: The new eclipse installation probably hasn't created the folder yet. That's why you don't see it.

Comment: so I have copied ~/.eclipse folder to OSX, but eclipse is not recognizing any of my preferences. any ideas?

Comment: The top directory in .eclipse is a number like 1881004202 so I would assume is random - so I would create a config in OSX and then copy data to that -a also files in there seem to be OSX specific - also look in directories around eclipse.app

Comment: my bad, the settings are there I guess. but not all of them. projects are there for example, but 'Available Software Sites' aren't. thanks for the info though.

Comment: I have been using eclipse for a while now, and it never created the ~/.eclipse folder. I found out that everything is located in the eclipse folder that I downloaded from the internet.